# Javascript execute two functions addEventlistener and delay one of them

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener

On my site I have an addEventListener that executes the following code. The variables/constants are defined like this: `const header_search_form = document.querySelector('.header-search-form');`.

What I need is that this part of the code is executed with a delay of 2 seconds: `document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").focus();`. The other code should be executed normally, with the if condition also being respected. I already tried some things, but that didn't work.

```
header_search_button.addEventListener('click', onClickOpensearch);

function onClickOpensearch(){

if(header_search_container.classList.contains('open')){
    header_parent.classList.remove('open');
    header_search_background.classList.remove('open');
    document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").blur();
    document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").value = "";
} else {
    header_parent.classList.add('open');
    header_search_background.classList.add('open');
    document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").focus();
}
}
```

It would be great if someone could show me how to change the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works straight away:

```
} else {
    header_parent.classList.add('open');
    header_search_background.classList.add('open');
    setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").focus();
    }, 2000)
}
```

The same stuff using an arrow function:

```
} else {
    header_parent.classList.add('open');
    header_search_background.classList.add('open');
    setTimeout(() => {
       document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").focus();
    }, 2000)
}
```

Notice, it might blocks user interaction for 2 seconds, this isn't the best of the best practice.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not block user interaction. It places the callback to the end of the callstack and runs it when the time is over and other functions in the stack have been finished, but does not occupy the event loop to wait for the callback to finish.

Comment: It does. You must pass your DOM changes in `requestAnimationFrames()` or `requestIdleCallback()`. There is also the web animation api. Depending the  context. All machines aren't as fast or responsive as yours. On this case it's not much a little focus(), there isn't  DOM calculations.

Comment: The parts about `requestAnimationFrames()` and `requestIdleCallback()` are accurate. But it doesn't say anywhere on threads or docs that `setTimeout` blocks the user interaction. It does not work like, for example like `sleep(2000)` in Python does. Just run a timeout in your console and click anywhere on your page. It will still work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

you could use javascript `setTimeout` method which calls a function after a specified number of milliseconds

```
    header_search_button.addEventListener('click', onClickOpensearch);

    function onClickOpensearch(){

     if(header_search_container.classList.contains('open')){
         header_parent.classList.remove('open');
         header_search_background.classList.remove('open');
         document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").blur();
         document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").value = "";
      } else {
        header_parent.classList.add('open');
        header_search_background.classList.add('open');
        var headerSearchField =document.getElementById("header-search-field-input");
        setTimeout(() =>  headerSearchField.focus(), 2000);
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("header-search-field-input").focus();
}, 2000);
```